# iScroll jumps to top of list when list is updated

Tags: jquery, json, iscroll

I am making an dynamic list with JSON and iScroll and it works perfect. The issue is that my list is getting updated every 20 seconds and every time the list gets updated it jumps to the top of the list. How do I get passed this?

Here is my script:

```
var myScroll;

hoverClassRegEx = new RegExp('(^|\\s)iScrollHover(\\s|$)'),
removeClass = function () {
    if (this.hoverTarget) {
        clearTimeout(this.hoverTimeout);
        this.hoverTarget.className = this.hoverTarget.className.replace(hoverClassRegEx, '');
        this.target = null;
    }
};  

$(document).on('pageshow', function (){
    var userid=1,

    dataUrl = 'http://mypage.com/playermenu.php?callback=?&userid=' + userid,
    dataCallback = function (data) {
        var content = [];
        //var profile = [];
        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            content.push(val.list); // GETTING ALL THE GAMES //
            $('#userbar').html(val.profile); // FETCHING USERS DATA FOR PROFILEBAR //
        });
        $('#games').html(content.join('')).listview('refresh');
    },
    fetchData = function () {
        //myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
        //myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', { checkDOMChanges: true, hScrollbar: false, vScrollbar: false });
        myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', { checkDOMChanges: true, hScrollbar: false, vScrollbar: false, 
            onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) {
                var target = e.target;

                clearTimeout(this.hoverTimeout);

                while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;

                this.hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                    if (!hoverClassRegEx.test(target.className)) target.className = target.className ? target.className + ' iScrollHover' : 'iScrollHover';
                }, 80);

                this.hoverTarget = target;

                e.preventDefault();
            },
            onScrollMove: removeClass,
            onBeforeScrollEnd: removeClass
        });
        if (myScroll.isReady()){
            $.getJSON(dataUrl, dataCallback);
        }
    };
    fetchData();
    setInterval(fetchData, 20000);

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(loaded, 200);  }, false);

});
```

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: It would be perfect if you give an example using jsfiddle.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain - Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/jmansa/VmQeE/8/

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the 'rubber band effect' and is solcved by using myScroll.refresh()

See updated fiddle

> http://jsfiddle.net/VmQeE/10/
>
> myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
>   myScroll.refresh(),checkDOMChanges: true, hScrollbar: false,
>   vScrollbar: false,            onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) {
>                 var target = e.target;
>
> ```
>           clearTimeout(this.hoverTimeout);
>
>           while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;
>
>           this.hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
>               if (!hoverClassRegEx.test(target.className)) target.className = target.className ? target.className + ' iScrollHover' :
> ```
>
> 'iScrollHover';
>                 }, 80);

Comment: It doesn't seem to work... Are you sure that the myScroll.refresh() can be put where you put it?

Comment: But the iScroll part doesnt work? I cant scroll using the iScroll function in the windwow?